# getting index from inside the function

Tags: jquery

Using the following code I'm trying to get access to **index** from inside the function bound to play[index].click().

I've been trying couple things but can't figure it out.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( ".player" ).each(function( index ) {
        if (typeof play === 'undefined') {
            play = [];
        }

        play[index] = $(this).children('.button.play');

        play[index].on('click', function(e, index) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // index where are you?
            console.log( index );

        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

Html would go like this:

```
<div class="player">
    <a class="button play" href="" title=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: remove `index` from `function(e, index)` => `function(e)`

Comment: I put it in answer, enjoy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `function(e, index) {`. You are assigning "index " inside function, so now this is another variable. No need to do that, just remove (e, `index)`

```
    //index here
    play[index].on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // index where are you?
        console.log( index );

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You just don't pass index as a parameter to event because there is only `event` argument. You can however pass an object to event https://api.jquery.com/event.data/:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( ".player" ).each(function( index ) {
        if (typeof play === 'undefined') {
            play = [];
        }

        play[index] = $(this).children('.button.play');

        play[index].on('click', {value : index} ,function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // index accessible from this block
            console.log( e.data.value );

        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**
This is just a possibility as index is accessible from event. So you don't need to do this as index is accessible from each button.
This is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJyjzY).

Answer (score 0):

You have a parameter, `index`, with the same name as the variable in an outer scope that you want to use.

Javascript doesn't allow you access to variables in other scopes if the identifier is in use in the current scope.

You need to either rename the parameter or remove it altogether.